# Angular: custom directive not updating controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started to learn Angular not so long time ago and I'm trying to understand scope, binding and etc.

I have an order details controller:

```
orderApp.controller('OrderDetailsController', ['$http','$routeParams','$scope','config', function($http, $routeParams, $scope, config){

    var orderCtrl = this;
    orderCtrl.orderId = $routeParams.orderId;
    orderCtrl.order = {};
    orderCtrl.editingView = false;

   ...

}]);
```

On order details page I want to output all information about selected order. Also we need to give user ability to edit order. Information about editing mode is stored in orderCtrl.editingView.

I decided to create custom directive. If edit mode is off - display text, otherwise display input.

```
    orderApp.directive('editableText', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            property: '=property',
            editMode: '=editMode'
        },
        controller: 'OrderDetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'orderCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/pages/editable-text.html'
    }
});
```

This is template:

```
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="!editMode">{{property}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="editMode"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="property"></div>
```

And this is how I use directive in html files:

```
 <editable-text property="orderCtrl.order.coid" edit-mode="orderCtrl.editingView"></editable-text>
```

Text and input are switching when edit mode is on/off. Problem is that orderCtrl.order.coid property is not updated when I change it in input.

Before edit property looks like:
[image]

Turn on edit mode and change value:
[image]

Turn off edit mode and  we see old value:
[image]

Do I need to synchronise controller values and directive scope? I thought that with 2-ways binding it should happen automatically. Probably there is any other way to write this functionality? Will appreciate any help.

---

UPD

Directive code:

```
    orderApp.directive('editableText', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: {
            property: '=property',
            editMode: '=editMode'
        },
        controller: 'OrderDetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'orderCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/pages/editable-text.html'
    }
});
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="!orderCtrl.editMode">{{orderCtrl.property}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="orderCtrl.editMode"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="orderCtrl.property"/></div>
```

Directive usage:

```
 <editable-text property="orderCtrl.order.coid" edit-mode="orderCtrl.editingView"></editable-text>
```

I'm not sure that we really need to pass edit-mode attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bindToController: { ..scope properties.. }` option here inside your directive to make sure that isolated `scope` properties should get bounded to controller `this` context.

**Directive**

```
orderApp.directive('editableText', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: {
            property: '=property',
            editMode: '=editMode'
        },
        controller: 'OrderDetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'orderCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/pages/editable-text.html'
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="!orderCtrl.editMode">
     {{orderCtrl.property}}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="orderCtrl.editMode">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="orderCtrl.property"/>
</div>
```

> **Note:-** this above `bindToController: { ..scope properties.. }` option available for angular 1.4+ versions.

For Angular 1.3 > version & 1.4 > version you should use former way of doing it by having `bindingToController: true` to bind scope variable to controller context & do keep the varaibles inside `scope: { ...props... }`

```
scope: {
    property: '=property',
    editMode: '=editMode'
},
bindToController: true
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried code and value is not displayed at all. Should I change the way of passing attributes to directive?

Comment: could you please try udpated? & i don't understand one thing, how `orderCtrl` directive controller instance available for directive controller instantiate.. as I can see you have used it over here `<editable-text property="orderCtrl.order.coid" edit-mode="orderCtrl.editingView"></editable-text> `

Comment: Yes, it works. Do I understand right that there is no need to pass editMode parameter to directive? I can just directly use "orderCtrl.editingView" in directive template. What do you think?

Comment: @Tamara I think you misunderstood my answer..there is need to pass `editMode` parameter to directive so that directive scope will become isolated scope.. could you create plunkr of your problem..so that I can make help on it..

Comment: Ok, I have updated my post. I'm not sure that I call directive in a right way. But we need to pass at least 1 parameter/attribute to the directive - name of the property we want to display.

Comment: @Tamara I'm still wondering do you have `orderCtrl` controller alias at two places?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107667/discussion-between-tamara-and-pankaj-parkar).